# ng-change with value with leading zero - zero is gone controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, zero, angularjs-ng-change

I have an input field like this:

```
<input id="0900" type="radio" ng-model="formData.appointment_hour" ng-change="change(0900)" name="appointment" value="0900" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

But when I look in the function in my controller:

```
$scope.change = function(key){
    console.log(key);
};
```

My console logs `900`. The problem is that I don't want the leading zeros to be gone. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the result of `900` from `0900` is only because Javascipt parses all values beginning with 0 under 777 as octal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the value as a string:

```
<input id="0900" type="radio" ng-model="formData.appointment_hour" ng-change="change('0900')" name="appointment" value="0900" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```